# Save parsed links to a string or to an array java

Tags: java, parsing, url, web

```
String html = Jsoup.connect("www.example.com").get().html();
Scanner in = new Scanner(html);

String links ;
while(in.hasNext()){
    String line = in.nextLine();
    if(line.contains("sometext")){

String  links += line.substring(line.indexOf("http").line.indexOf("</a>") + "\n");

    }
```

I have the above code. It gets the HTML of a webpage using JSoup and after that, I want to save them to a string or to an array separated by new line. That's my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should kept using [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) for the retrieving and parsing the HTML. Also, jsoup's documentation [address this](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links).

```
String output = "";
// Get the webpage and parse it.
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
// Get the anchors with href attribute.
// Or, you can use doc.select("a") to get all the anchors. 
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
// Iterate over all the links and process them.
for (Element link : links) {
  output += link.attr("abs:href");
}
```